# Did Apollo 13 produce any scientific results?

Tags: apollo-13, scientific-data, science

Despite an explosion and other setbacks, Apollo 13 landed safely back on Earth on April 17, 1970.  Even though the astronauts did not make it to the lunar surface, **were any scientific results reported?**

*This concludes a [series honoring the 50th anniversary of Apollo 13](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1521/26446).  I hope you have found the questions interesting, and perhaps even given you hope that people can turn any disaster into "our finest hour".*

[image: the capsule appears from the heavens]

Comment: A special [chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106807/apollo-13-anniversary-series) has been created for any comments or questions you may have about the series.  Please use the comments below only for issues *directly* related to this question.

Answer (score 46):

It did, with the third rocket stage.  Instead of just becoming another object in solar orbit like the previous Apollo third stages, this time the third stage was sent into the Moon for a crash landing whose impact would be recorded on the seismometer installed by Apollo 12.  This test went off without a hitch and successfully returned data from the seismometer.  See [here](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/LRO/multimedia/lroimages/lroc-20100322-apollo13booster.html).

Answer (score 30):

In addition to crashing the Saturn V's S-IVB into the moon to collect seismic data from sensors installed by the crews of Apollo 11 and 12, several life sciences experiments were performed on the crew before and after Apollo 13. While all of the inflight experiments were canceled, researchers still managed to collect data on the cardiovascular's response to weightlessness, in addition to several others that you can read about [here](https://lsda.jsc.nasa.gov/Mission/miss/35).  The experiments were

- Apollo Flight Crew Cardiovascular Evaluations
- Apollo Flight Crew Vestibular Assessment
- Clinical Aspects of Crew Health
- Clinical Biochemistry
- Endocrine, Electrolyte, and Fluid Volume Changes Associated with Apollo Missions
- Hematology and Immunology Studies
- Microbiological Investigations
- Nutritional Studies
- Radiation Protection and Instrumentation

It should be noted that the data from Apollo 13 simply added to the datasets of ongoing studies.

Comment: Minor point: the NASA source I reference states "only the seismometer from Apollo 12 was available".  So we can't use Apollo 11 in the first sentence.  The rest is good enough for a +1.

Comment: Well, they got flight crew telemetry at least until Tom Hanks "got tired of the entire western world knowing how his kidneys were functioning."

Comment: @MooseBoys I was going to upvote your comment but I'll leave it at 13.

Comment: @Brian it's 14 now.  Might as well, uh, launch.  Maybe mine can get up to 13? ;-)